# Background image in a gridfield in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I am developed a GridField in Blackberry.I have added a background image which covers the full screen.Now i want to add an image on top of the background image and add the gridfield on that image,when i am adding the image on the background image and then add the gridfield,the gridfield goes below the image,but i want it on top of the image.

Answer (score 1):

You can call like:

```
vfm.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createBitmapBackground(your bitmap))
```

Or you can call the same method in a screen to set the background image to entire screen.

Answer (score 0):

You will likely have to use different Managers, or combine your fields/managers in a different manner than you are right now.  But, without seeing your code, I can't diagnose any further.